# How is it possible to encode String twice?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, encoding

I was Python programmer(Of course I am now, too), so I am familiar with Python encoding and decoding.

I was surprised at the fact that `Java` can encode String variables twice consecutively.

This is example code:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class OpenAPITest {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        String str = "안녕";   // Korean
        String utfStr = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(utfStr);
        String ms949Str = URLEncoder.encode(utfStr, "MS949");
        System.out.println(ms949Str);
    }
}
```

I wonder how it can encode string twice times.

In Python, version 3.x, once you encode `type 'str'` which consists of unicode string, then it converted to `type 'byte'` which consists of byte string. `type 'byte'` has only `decode()` function.

Additionally, I want to get same String values in `Python3` as the result value of `ms949Str` in my example code. Give me some advice, please. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @scottb How could it possible to encode String twice times consecutively in JAVA ?

Comment: Sidenote: "twice" means "two times". Therefore "twice times" is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know Python, besides you didn't say what Python method you were using anyway, but if the Python method converted a Python string into a `UTF-8` sequence of bytes, then you're using the wrong conversion method here, because that has nothing to do with **URL** Encoding.

`str.getBytes("UTF-8")` will return a `byte[]` with the Java string encoded in `UTF-8`.

`new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` will decode the byte array.

---

URL Encoding is about converting text into a string that is valid as a *component* of a full URL, meaning that all special characters must be encoded using `%NN` escapes. Non-ASCII characters has to be encoded too.

As an example, take the string `Test & gehört`. When URL Encoded, it becomes the following **string**:

```
Test+%26+geh%C3%B6rt
```

The string `Test & gehört` becomes the following sequence of **bytes** (displayed in hex) when used with `getBytes`:

```
54 65 73 74 20 26 20 67 65 68 c3 b6 72 74
```

Comment: Don't know Java, but what's difference between `str.getBytes('utf-8')` and `URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8")` ?. I think that both function as convert string to `utf-8` encoded bytes value, right?

Comment: you can also use Base64 class from apache labrary to encode string.

Comment: @user3595632 URL Encoding does a lot *more* that just UTF-8 encoding. It escapes characters that have special meaning to **URLs**. Unless you're specifically building a URL one component at a time, URL Encoding is *not* for you. URL "encoding"/escaping is similar to XML encoding/escaping, where special characters like `&` is encoded as `&amp;`. In URL encoding that gets encoded as `%26`, as you can see in the answer. Those encodings have nothing to do with UTF-8.